# Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details: call: switch(os, Linux = if (file.exists("/etc/os-release"))

Tags: r, installation, macos-big-sur

I am struggling to have my R started on my new mac from work (usually, I work on linux). In  macOS bigSur 11.4, I have download xquartz and then install R 4.1.3
all good except this

```
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: switch(os, Linux = if (file.exists("/etc/os-release")) {
  error: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

>sessionInfo()
Error in sessionInfo() : could not find function "sessionInfo"
```

So I tried to google it and found this https://github.com/jasp-stats/jasp-issues/issues/1131 and this https://github.com/jasp-stats/jasp-desktop/blob/development/Docs/user-guide/logging-howto.md
did not solve the issue. Please let me know if I need to provide other details.
Thank you

Comment: Is your Mac Intel-based or using Apple Silicon (i.e. M1, etc)?  The copy of R you are trying to install is the Intel one.  Where did you install it from?

Comment: yes,   Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,2
  Processor Name: Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
I have downloaded  R4.1.3.pkg  from  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: That all sounds fine.  Assuming your install went fine, my only guess is that you have some environment variables set (maybe from an earlier install), and they are messing things up.  The ones that R looks at during startup are  R_ENVIRON, R_HOME, R_PROFILE,  R_PROFILE_USER, R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES, and some others starting with "R_" that probably don't matter.  It will also look for some files if you don't specify --vanilla when running it.  To debug, I'd suggest opening Terminal, and running R using `R --vanilla`.  That should work, and then you can print `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Tried, that ```% R --vanilla 

During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
> sessionInfo()
Error in sessionInfo() : could not find function "sessionInfo"```
and when I tried. where R  it says. /usr/local/bin/R

Comment: Sounds like your installation is messed up, or your environment variables are.  If you do `ls -l /usr/local/bin/R` you should see a soft link to where it is installed.  On my system, I get `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R`.  I can see all the installed packages in the system library using `ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/library`.

Comment: Correct, I get the same, ```% ls -l /usr/local/bin/R 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  _developer  47 30 Mar 10:28 /usr/local/bin/R -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
                                                                                
 % ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/library
KernSmooth cluster  graphics nnet  etc ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243455/discussion-between-silchara-and-user2554330).